# How to draw a colored border around NSImage?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

I did some research but all the answers I got were for iOS, how can I draw a colored border around NSImage in OSX app? I tried using imageView property of NSImage to set it's border width and color, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try like this without creating subclass also it is possible. Also you can set the width ans radius accordingly:-

```
[imgView setWantsLayer:YES];
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
CGColorRef color = CGColorRetain([NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:100 blue:0 alpha:0.5f].CGColor);
[imgView.layer setBorderColor:color];
```

Comment: How to set background image for NSImageView Mr.Hussain. I tried to replace colorWithCalibrated with [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:....] in above code, but this doesn't seem to work, please help me, thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using colorWithPatternImage??

Comment: @HussainShabbir I want to set background image for NSImageView, I mean I have a letter image and that should be enclosed in a box(image). I could achieve it in ios, however struggling to do so in mac os, [here](http://pastebin.com/d38PMWYY) is my implementation code. Please help me, thanks :)

Comment: @HussainShabbir I solved my problem, thanks for the concern..unlocking focus after returning image solved the issue :)

Answer (score 6):

You could subclass NSView and do something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor orangeColor] set];

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path appendBezierPathWithRoundedRect:outerFrame xRadius:5 yRadius:5];
    [path setLineWidth:4.0];
    [path stroke];
}
```

and of course change the radius values depending if you want rounded corners or not.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 3**:

```
imagePreview.layer!.borderWidth = 10.0
imagePreview.layer!.cornerRadius = 8.0
imagePreview.layer!.masksToBounds = true
let color: CGColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
imagePreview.layer!.borderColor = color
```

Answer (score 0):

In **swift**:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    // Draw Border
    borderColor.set()
    let borderPath = NSBezierPath(rect: dirtyRect)
    borderPath.lineWidth = 2.0
    borderPath.stroke()
}
```