# add white border to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My question might be very easy for you.

I am trying to add white border to `UIImage` in my photo editing app. I found some questions and answers [How can i take an UIImage and give it a black border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354811/how-can-i-take-an-uiimage-and-give-it-a-black-border).

Most answers are for adding border to `UIImageView`. In my case, I need to add a border to `UIImage` with adjustable border width.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645303/how-to-draw-a-colored-border-around-nsimage/19651545#19651545

Comment: check my updated answer.. it will sove your problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the border properties on the CALayer by accessing the layer property of the UIImageView.

First, add Quartz

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Set properties:

```
[[yourImageView layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[yourImageView layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
```

### Edit 1

As you need to save the image with border, use below.

```
- (UIImage *)addBorderToImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef bgimage = [image CGImage];
    float width = CGImageGetWidth(bgimage);
    float height = CGImageGetHeight(bgimage);

        // Create a temporary texture data buffer
    void *data = malloc(width * height * 4);

    // Draw image to buffer
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data,
                                                 width,
                                                 height,
                                                 8,
                                                 width * 4,
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), bgimage);

    //Set the stroke (pen) color
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);

    //Set the width of the pen mark
    CGFloat borderWidth = (float)width*0.05;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, borderWidth);

    //Start at 0,0 and draw a square
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0.0, 0.0);    
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0.0, height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, width, height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, width, 0.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0.0, 0.0);

    //Draw it
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

        // write it to a new image
    CGImageRef cgimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage];
    CFRelease(cgimage);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);

        // auto-released
    return newImage;
}
```

[Reference](http://matt.coneybeare.me/adding-a-border-around-a-uiimage-with-core-gr/)

Comment: thank you for your help. but it just add border to UIImageView. For me, I need to add border to image .So when user save the photo, it will be saved with white border.Is there any way to add border to UIImage,please?

Comment: This is not adding a border. it is painting over the image and even border width would be wrong since half of it is drawn outside the bounds. it would be simpler to create a new image context with increased size, fill with border color, draw the image to the center and then create a neq image from the context.

Comment: @lilith : happy to help.. enjoy coding...

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a new context and then re-draw the image into that:

```
UIImage *image = yourImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
UIRectFrame(CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height));
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`UIRectFrame` draws a 1 point border. If you need more you'll need to use a `UIBezierPath` instead.

```
UIImage *image = yourImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
path.lineWidth = 2.0;
[path stroke];
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

For a complete implementation as a category on `UIImage`:

**UIImage+Bordered.h**

```
@interface UIImage (Bordered)

-(UIImage *)imageBorderedWithColor:(UIColor *)color borderWidth:(CGFloat)width;

@end
```

**UIImage+Bordered.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (Bordered)

-(UIImage *)imageBorderedWithColor:(UIColor *)color borderWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [color setStroke];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    path.lineWidth = width;
    [path stroke];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}

@end
```

Then to use it its as simple as:

```
UIImage *image = yourImage;
UIImage *borderedImage = [image imageBorderedWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] borderWidth:2.0];
```